# Spark DataFrame: join stuck on the same stage

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on joining two large datasets with 17M and 2.2M row count.
[image]

Partition size of the two datasets are:

mob_join_set:

[image]

dth_join_set:

[image]

Job is always stuck on the last two tasks of the join:

[image]

Have even tried G1GC and spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=500, spark.default.parallelism=500
But no success.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are there partitiones with only Null values?

Comment: Sounds like you might have a data skew. Check the join keys on both dataframes using groupBy(K1, K2).count().orderby($"count".desc). If there are far too many values of one K1, K2, etc combination, that means they all go to the same partition during join stage.